# Website Crash and Error

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I was working on my Wordpress last night and went to open the dashboard in a new tab and suddenly now I can't log in or view my site, I just keep getting these error messages:

"Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /home/caschica/public_html/connect.php on line 2"

"Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress."

www.caschicago.com

www.caschicago.com/wp

Comment: What happens with FTP and phpMyAdmin? The best way to remove it would be to remove the folder and the entries from the wp_config table.

Comment: Update your WordPress. This API was removed in PHP 7 and warning was given in PHP 5.5 so you're using code that's way out of date.

Comment: Removed the Wordfence folder and updated WP and I'm back up and running. Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

Another reason to use mysqli or pdo, since php 6 or 7 it is not supported anymore to use mysql.
I cant believe how many times this is the answer on SO.